# Why aren't my sublime-anaconda gutter marks showing up?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I was watching Corey Schafer's video on YouTube on 'Setting up a Python Developer Environment in sublime Text'.
I installed the anaconda package, but for some reason, the gutter marks (for linting) are not showing in the line number column.

I have not altered the default settings.
I have added Corey's user settings to the sublime-anaconda user settings file:

```
{
"auto_formatting": true,
"autoformat_ignore":
[
],
"pep8_ignore":
[
    "E501"
],
"anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
"anaconda_gutter_marks": true,
"anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
"display_signatures": false,
"disable_anaconda_completion": true,
"python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
}
```

I should note that I have also tried adding:

```
"anaconda_gutter_marks": true,
```

to no avail.

I have also saved the settings and restarted sublime text.

Comment: What version of Sublime are you using, and what OS are you on?

Comment: I'm running Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `"python_interpreter"` setting to the actual path of the `python.exe` executable on your system. Opening `cmd` and entering `which python` may be helpful in finding it. Once you've found it, change and `\` characters to `/` - for example, `C:\Python38\python.exe` would become `C:/Python38/python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Where you've copied the code from correy's GitHub there is a line called `"python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3"` just delete that line and restart sublime and the errors should be showing again.

Check the screenshot:

[image: the picture]